# why statement is getting called before await function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I have created a demo for learning async and await

Here it is happening that a statement is executed before await function..

According to me

output should be A   second   Z First

but its giving

output : A Z second first

here is my coding

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  first() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      print('first');
    });
  }

  second() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('second');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Async demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: TextButton(
            child: Text('Click Me'),
            onPressed: () async {
              print('A');
              first();
              await second();
              print('Z');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this.

```
    first() async  {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
          print('first');
        });
      }

    second() async   {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('second');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use async await in `first()` and `second()` function also before `Future.delayed()`

Answer (score 0):

this code is working fine .According to you output  " A second Z First"

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  first() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
      print('first');
    });
  }

  second() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('second');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Async demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: TextButton(
            child: Text('Click Me'),
            onPressed: () async {
              print('A');
              first();
              await second();
              print('Z');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is output:

```
  Performing hot restart...
    Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
    Restarted application in 397ms.
    A
    second
    Z
    first
```

Comment: yes but I did not add async and await in my first and second method,It is solved by adding it